# firebaseConfig безопасность

Tags: reactjs, git, firebase, безопасность, config

**Господа профи! Разъясните.**

Начал изучать Firebase, пробую авторизацию, сделал проект на React формочка логина email и пароль, залил на Github, вроде ничего сложного все работает авторизация проходит. Но я задумался на сколько безопасно хранить конфиг в открытом виде, ну по идее в JS все на клиенте и раскопать его не сложно. В итоге запушил все и конфиг тоже, проект открыт там ничего ценного нет.

**Так вот вопрос:**

*Стоит ли убирать мой конфиг Firebase из публичного репозитория и что вообще нехороший человек сможет с ним сделать?*

Answer (score 0):

Безопасно.
Например для записи данных или их чтении - есть правила безопасности.
А для входа в аккаунт нужен пароль и логин пользователя.